# Openpyxl cell formatted as text

Tags: excel, text, openpyxl, cell

Good morning,
I have to report values via openpyxl in an excel table, these are values for calculating working time, at the end of the excel table I have to add them up, the problem is that they are formatted as text when I want to copy them into excel...

```
bezahltezeit_min_excel = bezahltezeit_minuten / 1440
starttime_excel = float(IcsStartData.strftime("%M")) / 1440 + float(IcsStartData.strftime("%H")) * 60 / 1440
endtime_excel = float(endingtime.strftime("%M")) / 1440 + float(endingtime.strftime("%H")) * 60 / 1440
schichtdauer_excel = float(IcsSchichtDauer.strftime("%M")) / 1440 + float(IcsSchichtDauer.strftime("%H")) * 60 / 1440

ws.append([f'{Datetime}',f'{diensteninfo}'f'{tagesinfo2}',f'{soup_funktion}',
                                f'{starttime_excel}',f'{endtime_excel}',f'{schichtdauer_excel}',f'{bezahltezeit_min_excel}'
                                ,f'{uberzeit_netto}',
                                f'{nacht_zeit_zul_10}',f'{nachtzulage}',
                                f'{wegzeiten}'])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTgb4.jpg)

Comment: Why are you surprised? You're forcefully adding the all the data as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Why use the f string on individual fields?
In this example

```
...
a = 0.5430559
b = 0.8555559
c = 0.3125
e = 'TAG'
f = 'Name'

ws.append([f'{a}', f'{b}', f'{c}'])
ws.append([a, b, c, f'{e}-{f}'])
```

The 1st append will be all Text values. The 2nd append the numbers are float values.
There is no need to use f string in your append unless like in the 2nd append you have two text fields you want to add to the same cell with a separator. That field is a text value added as text.

[image: Appended data]